# How to solve an expression from user input not using parentheses?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, expression

I'm trying to write a program that evaluates an expression the user inputs. I know I need to have separate methods so It evaluates multiplication and division first then adds the addition and subtraction afterwards. This is what I got so far. When I try anything involving multiplication or division, like 6*6, it will only print the first character, which would be just '6' in this instance. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Expressions {
String e;

void setExpressions(String exp) {
    e = exp;
}
String evaluate() {
    String n = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++)
        if (e.charAt(i) == '*' || e.charAt(i) == '/') {  
            n += e.charAt(i);
        }
        else if (e.charAt(i) == '+' || e.charAt(i) == '/') {
            evaluateMD();
            n = "";
        }
        else 
            n += e.charAt(i);
    return n;
}
int evaluateMD () {
    int r = 1;
    int n = 0;
    char op = '*';

    for (int i = 0; i < evaluate().length(); i++)
        if (evaluate().charAt(i) == '*' || evaluate().charAt(i) == '/') {
            if (op == '*') 
                r *= n;
            else 
                r /= n;   
            n = 0;
            op = evaluate().charAt(i);
        }
        else if (evaluate().charAt(i) == '*' || evaluate().charAt(i) == '/')
            n = 0;
        else //digits
            n = n*10 + (evaluate().charAt(i)-'0');
    if (op == '+') //last operation
        r *= n;
    else 
        r /= n;

    return r;

}
int evaluateAS() {
    //e has +, - only, multiple digit numbers 
    int r = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char op = '+';

    for (int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++)
        if (e.charAt(i) == '+' || e.charAt(i) == '-') {
            if (op == '+') 
                r += n;
            else 
                r -= n;   
            n = 0;
            op = e.charAt(i);
        }
        else if (e.charAt(i) == '*' || e.charAt(i) == '/')
            n = 0;
        else //digits
            n = n*10 + (e.charAt(i)-'0');
    if (op == '+') //last operation
        r += n;
    else 
        r -= n;

    return r;
}
}
 public class hw10 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Expressions myE = new Expressions();

    System.out.print("Enter E:");//E for expression
    String e = in.next();

    myE.setExpressions(e);
    //int r = myE.evaluate1();

    int r = myE.evaluateAS();

    System.out.println(e+" = "+r);



}
}
```

Comment: Throw it away and look up 'recursive descent expression parser' or 'Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm'. Parentheses aren't your buggest problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line

```
if (op == '+') //last operation
```

in the evaluateMD method to

```
if (op == '*') //last operation
```

,changing the return type of the method to double and making  r and n doubles produces better results for the evaluateMD, but really you're overall procedure needs an overhaul, if not complete abandonment.

I think your it would be better if your evaluate method only returned the answer to the calculation.

It would only ever need to store 2 values at most: (in the case that you have an AS operation you would store it if the next operator was MD since MD needs to be evaluated first, but once the MD operation (which could involve more than one operator or more than one instance of the same operator i.e. 4*5*6 or 4/3*2) is computed you can then perform the 'waiting' AS immediately. For MD operations, you'd just store the latest update each time, as you almost had working in your evaluateMD method (which I think works with the modification I put at the top. If it doesn't feel free to ask me about it as I did make a few other changes).

This is an improvement on the method you were attempting, but as I said there may well be methods which are better still mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I needed to write arithmetic expressions parser, I would use pretty simple approach: get the input from user, translate it into [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (take a look at section named *Shunting-yard algorithm*), and evaluate it.
Robert Lafore in his "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" has pretty easy explanation of both algorithms - translation from infix to RPN and evaluation of expressions written in RPN, with the source code, so you can see how it can be implemented. After you read it, it'll be easy to mix both algorithms into one - take a look at [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459109/why-do-we-need-to-transform-arithmetic-expressions-into-reverse-polish-notation) on this topic.